# DataTables: deleting a row and the adding another makes the deleted row reappear

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having a similar problem to [Deleted Rows appear back upon adding new row DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813626/deleted-rows-appear-back-upon-adding-new-row-datatables) but his solution about using the `row().delete().draw(false);` didn't work for me.

I have this table where I need to add and delete rows. Adding and deleting work fine for the most part except when I add a row, delete it, then add a new one. When I add a new one the deleted row reappears along with the new one.

This is the javascript code I use to create the table when the first row is added and to add additional rows

```
$('body').on('click', ".btn-dataset", function(){

        $("#div-warn").empty();

        if( !$('#dst-num').val() || !$('#questionnaire').val() || !$('#dst-subjectnum').val() ){
            var warn = '<p><b>The main information about the dataset is required.</b></p>';
            $(warn).appendTo('#div-warn');
        }else{
            var num_dataset = $('#dst-num').val();
            var questionnaire = $('#questionnaire').val(); 
            var num_subjects = $('#dst-subjectnum').val();
            var info_dataset = $('#dst-info').val();
            $('#dst-num').val('');
            $('#questionnaire').val('');
            $('#dst-subjectnum').val('');
            $('#dst-info').val('');

            if( $('#dataset-table').length ){

                var et = $('#dataset-table').DataTable();
                et.row.add( [
                    num_dataset,
                    questionnaire,
                    num_subjects,
                    info_dataset,
                    '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-row"></span></a>'
                ] ).draw(false);

            }else
            {
                var html = '<table class="table table-hover display" id="dataset-table">';
                html += '<caption><span id="table-title">Datasets</span></caption>';
                html += '<thead><tr><th><b>Dataset Number</b></th><th><b>Questionnaire Name</b></th><th><b>Number of Subjects</b></th><th><b>Information on the dataset</b></th><th class="no-sort"></th></tr></thead><tbody>';
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + num_dataset + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + questionnaire + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + num_subjects + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + info_dataset + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-row"></span></a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
                html += '</tbody></table>';
                $(html).appendTo('#div-dataset');

                $('#dataset-table').DataTable( {
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                      { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ "no-sort" ] } ], 
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "scrollY": "200px",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "paging": false,
                    "info": false
                } );
            }

        }
    });
```

The relevant part here when adding the new row is this

```
            var et = $('#dataset-table').DataTable();
            et.row.add( [
                num_dataset,
                questionnaire,
                num_subjects,
                info_dataset,
                '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-row"></span></a>'
            ] ).draw(false);
```

Now the code I use to remove a row is this

```
function deleteRow(obj){

    var tbl = $(obj).closest('table');

    var tr = $(obj).closest('tr');

    tbl.DataTable();

    tr.remove().draw(false);
}
```

I have several tables so that's why I use the `.closest()` function to figure out where the user clicked to delete the row.

Any idea of what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. Basically I had to initialize the table as a Datatable before defining the tr variable like this. And then I could use the row method.

```
function deleteRow(obj){

    var tbl = $(obj).closest('table').DataTable();

    var tr = $(obj).closest('tr');

    tbl.row(tr).remove().draw(false);
}
```